# How to send arguments from redux-saga watcher to AsyncFunction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

According to my understanding for every action in UI there is a `saga-watcher` which will grab the
actionType and call a `asyncFunction` to fetch/post data from remote server

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('SOME_WATCHER_ACTION', fetchAsync)
}
```

and `fetchAsync` will performe actual `api` call

```
export function* fetchAsync() {
  // actual fetch from remote server api call 
  // callapi('/someUrl', someData)
  yield put({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
}
```

I want to make `fetchAsync` generic someting like this

```
export function* genericFetchAsync(someUrl, someData, someAction) {
  // actual fetch from remote server api call 
   // let resp = callapi('/someUrl', someData)
  yield put({ type: someAction: payload:  resp })
}
```

So that every watcher can call it like this

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('SOME_WATCHER_ACTION', 
  fetchAsync('SOME_ACTION', somedata, someUrl))
}
```

Comment: But how do `somedata` and `someUrl` make their way into `watcherSaga()`??

Answer (score 0):

You can put some params in the action creator's payload.

And call them in you fetchAsync like that:

```
export function * fetchAsync({ payload }) {}
```

The payload is passed automatically, so no need to do anything additional in your `watcherSaga`